# Javascript: get iframe id within loaded page

Tags: javascript, iframe

I've got a page that has an iframe. Every time the page loads, iframe gets unique id and name assigned to it. I can get the iframe name within loaded iframe like so:

```
alert(parent.window.frames[window.name].name);
```

But when i try to get the id value:

```
alert(parent.window.frames[window.name].id);
```

I get `undefined`?

Is it possible to get the id attribute of the iframe within loaded page?

---

http://jsfiddle.net/cqFtB/

---

```
<iframe id="lyygi8stwZSANUEh" src="http://example.com" name="zma82vRVe18xbAqW" title="Awesome Iframe">
```

example.com:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Awesome Iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        alert(parent.window.frames[window.name].name);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try `window.frameElement.id` in the iframe.

Comment: The above gives the following error:
`Permission denied to access property 'id'`

Comment: That can happen if the iframe and the page containing it are from different origins.  Are they in your case?

Comment: Boris, you are correct, they are from different origins. But how come i can access `name`, `location`, etc. attributes without any issues? Does this only apply to `ID`?

Comment: Walking through the frames array is sort of special-cased so you can do it on cross-origin windows.  And `name` may be too....  But note that you can't access `parent.location.href`, for example.  The same-origin restriction applies to most DOM properties; anything that would give you information about the other-origin document is off-limits, by default.

Comment: Thanks for that, guess i'll have to stick with `name` and do some string manipulation to get desired outcome.

Comment: In my case I get `null` on `window.frameElement` with a cross-origin iframe. @BorisZbarsky you mentioned that it can be done on cross-origin windows. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Per current spec, you get null in the cross-origin situation, instead of an object that you can't get any properties from.  The net result is the same, of course: you can't get the id cross-origin.

Answer (score 0):

In the iframe this is working for me. But only if the iframe and the parent share the same domain:

```
this.frameElement.attributes.id
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to insert the name of the iframe:

```
alert(parent.window.frames['zma82vRVe18xbAqW'].name);
```

Comment: the original question is asking what happens if you do not know the id