# get element by id from parent tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

My DOM is as below.

```
<html><head>...</head><body><script>...</script>
<iframe id="frame">
    #document
    <html>...</html> <!-- 2 -->
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I am binding partial in `iframe` (i.e. html 2). In html_2 partial, I am calling `document.ready` to get `id` of `iframe` using `getElementById`, but I am getting `null`. How to get id and other attribute values of `iframe`?

Comment: first: why are you using iframes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864505/javascript-get-iframe-id-within-loaded-page

Comment: get id of iframe using getElementById??? What id are you using in getElementById to get the iframe, whose id is "frame"?

Comment: `My html is as below.` no it isn't, guaranteed - that's maybe your DOM, not your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this as below,

```
$("#iframe", parent.document).attr("id");
```

BTW, Thanks all who answered and helped me by valued comments.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("iframe").each(function() {
  alert($(this).attr("id"));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>...</head>

<body>
  <script>
    ...
  </script>
  <iframe id="frame">

  </iframe>
  <iframe id="frame1">

  </iframe>
  <iframe id="frame2">

  </iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

1. Use `.attr("id")`
2. For multiple iframe use `.each()` to iterate iver all iframe
3. Use this to get current iframe

Comment: I have added all jquery needed. and alert gives me null. I already tried that.

Comment: then it is better if you can provide a demo or snippet to show what you having now.

Comment: There is one html page from where I am pointing a javascript. In this script, I am calling a function that creates iframe (with src = controller method to get partial). In this partial, i am pointing another js, in this js, there is document.ready where I want attribute values of iframe. actually in Iframe, as parent, the partial binds.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.document.getElementById("div1")
```

Comment: What is `div1`.? Is it in iframe or html_2 (in my case)...?

Comment: @DhavalR It'll be an element inside the `iframe` HTML